# Post a photo to an Album on a Facebook fan page without being the admin,

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

From my iOS application, i would like to post a photo to a fan page where **i am not** the admin.
I am doing well with that code:

```
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image_, 90);
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"hello", @"message",
                                imageData, @"source",
                                accessToken, @"access_token",
                                nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"{pageID}/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     DLog(@"error %@",error);
     DLog(@"result %@",result);
 }];
```

But now, i want to that photo **comes to a specific album of the fan page**. I tried to specify the "albumId" like at the Path: {albumID}/photos. It post it correctly but to my wall an not in a album of the fan page.